# Unity Error : Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that an explicit value for android:exported be defined when intent filters are present

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, build, apk

I encountered this problem when trying to create the application and install it on the device by (Build & Run)

**Unity version : 2018.4.36f1**

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to install APK to device. Please make sure the Android SDK is installed and is properly configured in the Editor. See the Console for more details.
C:/Users/msi/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s "c8e0d8ba" install -r "C:\Users\msi\Desktop\Unity\Antura_arabic-master\jj.apk"

stderr[
adb: failed to install C:\Users\msi\Desktop\Unity\Antura_arabic-master\jj.apk: Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED: Failed parse during installPackageLI: /data/app/vmdl1523869641.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #70): com.unity.androidnotifications.UnityNotificationRestartOnBootReceiver: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that an explicit value for android:exported be defined when intent filters are present]
]
stdout[
Performing Streamed Install
]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <267278aa48b840c7a0e7281223ea050e>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <267278aa48b840c7a0e7281223ea050e>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <267278aa48b840c7a0e7281223ea050e>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.ADB.RunInternal (System.String[] command, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <267278aa48b840c7a0e7281223ea050e>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.ADB.Run (System.String[] command, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <267278aa48b840c7a0e7281223ea050e>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidDevice.Exec (System.String[] command, System.String errorMsg) (at <267278aa48b840c7a0e7281223ea050e>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidDevice.Install (System.String apkfile) (at <267278aa48b840c7a0e7281223ea050e>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidDeploymentTargetsExtension+<UploadAPK>c__AnonStorey3.<>m__0 () (at <267278aa48b840c7a0e7281223ea050e>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidDeploymentTargetsExtension.UploadAPK (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildProperties buildProperties, UnityEditor.Android.AndroidDevice device, UnityEditor.Android.AndroidDeploymentTargetsExtension+LaunchProgressTaskManager taskManager) (at <267278aa48b840c7a0e7281223ea050e>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidDeploymentTargetsExtension+<LaunchBuildOnTarget>c__AnonStorey0.<>m__2 () (at <267278aa48b840c7a0e7281223ea050e>:0)
UnityEditor.ProgressTaskManager.Run () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Utils/ProgressBarUtils.cs:71)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidDeploymentTargetsExtension.LaunchBuildOnTarget (UnityEditor.DeploymentTargets.IDeploymentTargetsMainThreadContext context, UnityEditor.BuildProperties buildProperties, UnityEditor.DeploymentTargets.DeploymentTargetId targetId, UnityEditor.ProgressHandler progressHandler) (at <267278aa48b840c7a0e7281223ea050e>:0)
UnityEditor.DeploymentTargets.DeploymentTargetManager.LaunchBuildOnTarget (UnityEditor.BuildProperties buildProperties, UnityEditor.DeploymentTargets.DeploymentTargetId targetId, UnityEditor.ProgressHandler progressHandler) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/DeploymentTargets/DeploymentTargetManager.cs:45)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer+<LaunchOnTargets>c__AnonStorey1.<>m__0 () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:210)
UnityEditor.ProgressTaskManager.Run () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Utils/ProgressBarUtils.cs:71)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.LaunchOnTargets (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget buildTarget, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport buildReport, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] launchTargets) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:229)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.Launch (UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <267278aa48b840c7a0e7281223ea050e>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.LaunchPlayer (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildLaunchPlayerArgs args) (at <267278aa48b840c7a0e7281223ea050e>:0)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Launch (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget buildTarget, System.String path, System.String productName, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport buildReport) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:173)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:179)
```

**Custom AndroidMainifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.eshtaya.alhoroof" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:installLocation="preferExternal">
  <application android:isGame="true" android:icon="@mipmap/app_icon">
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector" android:exported="true" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale|layoutDirection|density" android:hardwareAccelerated="false">
      <intent-filter android:exported="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
    </activity>
    <meta-data android:name="unity.build-id" android:value="3141cadb-28f9-4b2a-aee5-29a9a71789ac" />
    <meta-data android:name="unity.splash-mode" android:value="1" />
    <meta-data android:name="unity.splash-enable" android:value="True" />
  </application>
  <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.distinct" android:required="false" />
</manifest>
```

added android:exported="true" to AndroidMainifest.xml but not working

please help me

Comment: Look into the merged Manifest file. Maybe this happened due to a third-party library.

Comment: how i can do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Set android:exported:
Open your project's AndroidManifest.xml file and locate the UnityNotificationRestartOnBootReceiver element within the  tag.
Add the following attribute to the element:

```
android:exported="true"
```

Here in your manifest there is no UnityNotificationRestartOnBootReceiver element within the  tag. May be it is inside your Unity library manifest.Hence *Update the Unity library to the latest version*

Comment: how i can update the Unity library ??

Comment: Because when I update the project to the latest Unity editor, I see a lot of problems

Comment: upgrade the dependencies in the build.gradle file to the latest version

Comment: or else you can done thing, downgrade the compile and target sdk version to  API level 30 (Android 11) but you cannot upload your apk to the Play store.